# Clear all Y Coordinates , given a X coordinate in PointCollection C#

Tags: c#, .net

I wanted to know is there any built in method to clear all the Y Points if i have dX point in Point Collection , let's say i have a point

```
new System.Windows.Point(dX, dY)
```

I'm trying to clear the whole dY for dX + 1.

I'm trying to clear a Line which gets drawn from the previous loop , i can create a loop to clear it , but i wanted to know if there is any built in optimal method to accomplish that.

Thank you

Comment: What do mean with clear the Y values? A point must contain both Y and X coordinates. Do you want to set those to 0? Either way there's no inbuilt method that does this.

Comment: Yes , i wanted to set it to 0 , but , i guess i need to set both X and Y to 0 , so that the next point gets cleared , thanks for your help

Comment: You can set Y to 0 without changing the X value but why wouldn't you simply remove the unnecessary items from your collection on the next loop / reinitialize the collection?

Comment: I want to clear the line which is drawn in previous loop , when the new line appears , i want the old line to remove itself one point at a time , not all at once .

Comment: OK, now that's something entirely different. You should rephrase your question then. When do you want to delete the points? When a new one is added or periodically? Which points do you want to delete: Last In / First out?

Comment: There is nothing built-in. You can use Linq to create shorter code but it will neither be faster nor easier to code or read than a loop.